# StructureMap and Methods injections

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap

I use Structure Map to resolve contructors injections like this

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IDependency _dependency;

    public MyClass(IDependency dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }
// my methods
}
```

And I have some class Dependency : IDependency

and in StructureMap config I have

```
public static IContainer Initialize()
        {
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.For<IDependency>().Use<Dependency>();
            });
            return ObjectFactory.Container;
        }
```

Everything workf fine

But in other controller I need to make method injection

```
public ActionResult(IDependency dependency)
{
    dependency.DoSomething();
}
```

And I want to have my Dependency class in dependency variable

Comment: Can you explain why you think you need method injection?

Comment: i need to use dependency in only one method

Comment: That I understand, but this hardly helps. I suspect that there is something wrong with your design and like to help you with that, but need more context. Can you show more code? Show for instance when you are injecting this.

Comment: We have a use case where a library is controlling object lifetime and calling a particular method but we need new service instances created and then injected each time the method is called. We have a custom lifecycle to do this for us, but we have to call ObjectFactory.GetInstance inside the method, which we don't like. We would love for method injection instead, but as far as I can tell, StructureMap does not support that.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would have IDependency injected in the constructor (or a setter) and assign it to a private class member that you can then use in your methods.

```
private readonly IDependency _dependency;

public MyClass(IDependency dep)
{
    this._dependency = dep;
}

public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    _dependency.DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@dave I agree with your answer but consider that MyClass is a registered with Shared/Singleton scope in StructureMap. In this case if I inject the dep into MyClass it will imply that I'm holding a reference to dep object throughout the lifetime of the application. Sounds like memory drain to me.

I recently got into the same situation and finalized on injecting StructureMap's IContainer into the constructor (instead of all the other nonsense object) and use that to get the object as and when required.

```
private readonly IContainer _container;

public MyClass(IContainer con)
{
    this._container = con;
}

public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var _dependency = _container.GetInstance<IDependency> ();
    _dependency.DoSomething();
}
```

This way my injected object becomes scoped to the MyAction() method and becomes ready to be consumed by GC